# How to patch an array into formarray

Tags: angular, angular8, formbuilder, formarray, formgroups

```
 this.formgroup = formbuilder.group({
      ordering_data: formgroup.array([this.createOrder()]),
    });
```

```
  createOrder(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      order: [null, [Validators.required]],
      section_menu_id: [null, [Validators.required]],
    });
  }
```

Api Result

```
[
  {
    "order": 0,
    "section_menu_id": 3
  },
  {
    "order": 1,
    "section_menu_id": 1
  },
  {
    "order": 2,
    "section_menu_id": 6
  },
]
```

I try to show all those data from api result on my form input.
Can someone tell me how to patch the api result into formgroup. Thanks in advance

Comment: When did you get your data ? You need to initializate the form with order and section_menu_id. I don't see where you do this

Comment: i got the data on ngOnInit @Emilien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my projects, I do something like this :

```
const data = [
  {
    "order": 0,
    "section_menu_id": 3
  },
  {
    "order": 1,
    "section_menu_id": 1
  },
  {
    "order": 2,
    "section_menu_id": 6
  },
];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.formgroup = this.fb.group({
    ordering_data: this.fb.array(this.data.map(item => this.createOrder(item))),
  });
}

createOrder(item?: any): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    order: [item ? item.order : null, Validators.required],
    section_menu_id: [item ? item.section_menu_id : null, Validators.required],
  });
}
```

Comment: its worked for me , but idont know why first of my value of my array object ([0]) kinda weird.. order: null, section_menu_id: 3. the rest of them is right

Comment: @Benni I've edited my post, please check the createOrder function

Comment: yeah now it fully work, thank you ;D . Anw it got some typo on ur code sir `section_menu_id: [item ? item.section_menu_id || null, Validators.required] ` , it should be `section_menu_id: [item ? item.section_menu_id : null, Validators.required] `

Comment: @Benni Super ! Yeah god I've edited my post again :P Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
this.formGroup.controls.ordering_data.patchValue(apiResult);
```

Cannot test it locally. Maybe you could provide a stackblitz?

Comment: yeah i have tried that, but the result isnt as expected. this is the resulted when i tried with that code

{
  "ordering_data": [
    {
      "order": 0,
      "section_menu_id": 3
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

consider below but I didn't test it;

```
interface Order {
  order: number;
  section_menu_id: number;
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.formgroup = formbuilder.group({
     ordering_data: formgroup.array([]),
  });
}

createOrder(o: Order): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
     order: [o.order, [Validators.required]],
     section_menu_id: [o.section_menu_id, [Validators.required]],
  });
}

getOrders() {
   this.http.get(url).subscribe(ordersResponse: Order[]) => {
     const ordering_data = this.formgroup.get('ordering_data') as FormArray;
     ordersResponse.forEach((o: Order) => {
        ordering_data.push(this.createOrder(o.order, o.section_menu_id));
     }

     this.formgroup.updateValueAnDValidity();
   });
}
```